# Amazon Beanstalk - nginx configuration

Tags: nginx, deployment, amazon-ec2, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have recently deployed a Beanstalk application on EC2.
This application is deployed using Docker.
I have discovered that every Beanstalk EC2 machine comes with a nginx that acts as a proxy(I don't really understand why, not documented anywhere).
Now the problem is that I do not know which nginx should have its configuration optimized (worker_processes, worker_connections, etc.)

Now, I know what I do not want and that is to configure nginx in two places.
I also tried using passenger as standalone but passenger as standalone looks like nginx.

How do you manage this situation in production ?

- why is there a default nginx running on the AWS EC2 AMI in the first place ?
- you really configure two nginx ?
- is first nginx just a proxy(on the AWS EC2 machine) ?
- should not touch anything regarding topmost nginx ?
- isn't this first nginx also affected by concurrency and should be optimized ?